# Argo(events) Trigger an existing ClusterWorkflowTemplate using Sensor

Tags: argo-workflows, argo-events

I'm trying to trigger a pre existing `ClusterWorkflowTemplate` from a post request in argo/ argo-events.

I've been following the example [here](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-events/quick_start/), but i don't want to define the workflow in the sensor- I want to separate this.

I can't get the sensor to import and trigger the workflow, what is the problem?

```yaml
# kubectl apply -n argo-test -f templates/whalesay/workflow-template.yml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterWorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: workflow-template-submittable
spec:
  entrypoint: whalesay-template
  arguments:
    parameters:
      - name: message
        value: hello world
  templates:
    - name: whalesay-template
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: message
      container:
        image: docker/whalesay
        command: [cowsay]
        args: ["{{inputs.parameters.message}}"]
```

```yaml
# kubectl apply -n argo-events templates/whalesay/event-source.yml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: EventSource
metadata:
  name: webhook
spec:
  service:
    ports:
      - port: 12000
        targetPort: 12000
  webhook:
    # event-source can run multiple HTTP servers. Simply define a unique port to start a new HTTP server
    example:
      # port to run HTTP server on
      port: "12000"
      # endpoint to listen to
      endpoint: /example
      # HTTP request method to allow. In this case, only POST requests are accepted
      method: POST
```

```yaml
# kubectl apply -n argo-events -f templates/whalesay/sensor.yml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: workflow
  namespace: argo-events
  finalizers:
    - sensor-controller
spec:
  template:
    serviceAccountName: operate-workflow-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: http-post-trigger
      eventSourceName: webhook
      eventName: example
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: workflow-trigger-1
        argoWorkflow:
          group: argoproj.io
          version: v1alpha1
          kind: Workflow
          operation: submit
          metadata:
            generateName: cluster-workflow-template-hello-world-
          spec:
            entrypoint: whalesay-template
            workflowTemplateRef:
              name: cluster-workflow-template-submittable
              clusterScope: true
```

```sh
# to launch
curl -d '{"message":"this is my first webhook"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://argo-events-51-210-211-4.nip.io/example
```

```json
# error
{
    "level": "error",
    "ts": 1627655074.716865,
    "logger": "argo-events.sensor-controller",
    "caller": "sensor/controller.go:69",
    "msg": "reconcile error",
    "namespace": "argo-events",
    "sensor": "workflow",
    "error": "temp ││ late workflow-trigger-1 is invalid: argoWorkflow trigger does not contain an absolute action",
}
```

References:

- [special-workflow-trigger.yaml](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-events/blob/master/examples/sensors/special-workflow-trigger.yaml)
- [cluster workflow templates](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/cluster-workflow-templates/)
- [spec](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-events/blob/master/api/sensor.md#argoworkflowtrigger)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to:

- Ensure that my service account `operate-workflow-sa` had cluster privileges
- Correct my `sensor.yml` syntax [spec](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-events/blob/master/api/sensor.md#argoworkflowtrigger)

Cluster privileges:

```yaml
# kubectl apply -f ./k8s/workflow-service-account.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: argo-events
  name: operate-workflow-sa
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: operate-workflow-role
  # namespace: argo-events
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - argoproj.io
    verbs:
      - "*"
    resources:
      - workflows
      - clusterworkflowtemplates
      - workflowtemplates
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: operate-workflow-role-binding
  namespace: argo-events
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: operate-workflow-role
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: operate-workflow-sa
    namespace: argo-events
```

sensor.yml (note the addition of the `serviceAccountName` for the workflow too):

```yaml
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: workflow
  namespace: argo-events
  finalizers:
    - sensor-controller
spec:
  template:
    serviceAccountName: operate-workflow-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: http-post-trigger
      eventSourceName: webhook
      eventName: example
  triggers:
    # https://github.com/argoproj/argo-events/blob/master/api/sensor.md#triggertemplate
    - template:
        name: workflow-trigger-1
        argoWorkflow:
          # https://github.com/argoproj/argo-events/blob/master/api/sensor.md#argoproj.io/v1alpha1.ArgoWorkflowTrigger
          group: argoproj.io
          version: v1alpha1
          resource: Workflow
          operation: submit
          metadata:
            generateName: cluster-workflow-template-hello-world-
          source:
            resource:
              apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
              kind: Workflow
              metadata:
                name: special-trigger
              spec:
                serviceAccountName: operate-workflow-sa
                entrypoint: whalesay-template
                workflowTemplateRef:
                  name: whalesay-template
                  clusterScope: true
```